# Python Web Scraping Code Crash After 10 result - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the prices of the various coins from this website: https://coinmarketcap.com/ with Python using the library: BeautifulSoup(bs4).

The For loop below work well for the first ten prices but then the code show the following error:

```
crypto_name = crypto_box.find('div',class_='sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 cPNAgw').p.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'p'
```

I already checked if the HTML code change for the eleventh coin but no, it is the same.

I also tried to run the Python code only for the eleventh coin and it works well without any problem.

So, what may be the problem that is triggering that error?

This is the Python Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/it/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

crypto_body = soup.find('tbody')
crypto_boxs = crypto_body.find_all('tr')
for crypto_box in crypto_boxs:
    crypto_name = crypto_box.find('div',class_='sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 cPNAgw').p.text
    crypto_price = crypto_box.find('div',class_='price___3rj7O').a.text
    print(f'Crypto Name: {crypto_name}')
    print(f'Crypto Price: {crypto_price}')
```

This is the HTML code for every coin. In particular, this  is from the eleventh coin

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="sc-7f3up6-1 dtMKRz">
            <span class="icon-Star"></span>
        </span></td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <p color="text2" font-size="0" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 etpvrL">11</p>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <div display="flex" class="sc-16r8icm-0 bjdvWe">
            <a href="/currencies/bitcoin-cash/" class="cmc-link">
                <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-0 jDQqmt">
                    <img class="coin-logo" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1831.png">
                    <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 cPNAgw">
                        <p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS">Bitcoin Cash</p>
                        <div class="sc-1teo54s-2 fZIJcI"><div class="sc-1teo54s-3 etWhyV">11</div>
                            <p color="text3" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol" font-size="1">BCH</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 XVjpr">
                <div aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="sc-1ouqzht-0 dwctMr">
                        <button class="x0o17e-0 kPvqGV" style="white-space: nowrap;">Buy</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="price___3rj7O "><a href="/currencies/bitcoin-cash/markets/" class="cmc-link">$696.51</a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
        <span class="sc-1v2ivon-0 fJLBDK">
            <span class="icon-Caret-up">
                
            </span>12.14%</span>
    </td><td style="text-align: right;">
    <span class="sc-1v2ivon-0 jvNdfB">
        <span class="icon-Caret-down">
            
        </span>38.61%</span>
</td><td style="text-align: right;">
    <p color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 kDEzev" style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <span class="ggzdxp-0 hWIeFI">$13.48B</span>
        <span class="ggzdxp-1 ftvydZ">$13,484,367,596</span>
    </p>
</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
    <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1anvaoh-0 gpGZZK">
        <a href="/currencies/bitcoin-cash/markets/" class="cmc-link">
            <p font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 kDEzev font_weight_500___2Lmmi" color="text">$5,914,262,210</p>
        </a>
        <p color="text2" font-size="0" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 etpvrL">8,222,076 BCH</p>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
        <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 g5oqcc-0 ebjmWp">
            <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 g5oqcc-1 fuJsZs">
                <div class="g5oqcc-4 gQCXde">
                    <span class="icon-Info">
                        
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
                <p font-size="1" font-weight="medium" color="text" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 hNpJqV">18,746,125 BCH</p>
            </div>
            <div width="160" class="qlsl66-0 jrRnei">
                <div width="143" class="qlsl66-1 gntYXo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="/currencies/bitcoin-cash/" class="cmc-link">
            <img src="https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1831.png" alt="1831-price-graph" class="tableGraph___c_IY- graphDown___2-1G6">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 dOJIkS" aria-expanded="false">
            <button class="x0o17e-0 ftvUnY sc-7pvt85-0 hmFKKb">
                
                <span class="icon-More-Vertical"></span></button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is the result after running the Python Code:

```
Crypto Name: Bitcoin
Crypto Price: €30,557.74
Crypto Name: Ethereum
Crypto Price: €2,030.75
Crypto Name: Tether
Crypto Price: €0.8173
Crypto Name: Binance Coin
Crypto Price: €264.41
Crypto Name: Cardano
Crypto Price: €1.23
Crypto Name: Dogecoin
Crypto Price: €0.275
Crypto Name: XRP
Crypto Price: €0.7661
Crypto Name: USD Coin
Crypto Price: €0.8161
Crypto Name: Polkadot
Crypto Price: €16.89
Crypto Name: Internet Computer
Crypto Price: €106.86
 File "/Users/******/*******/*******/*******/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    crypto_name = crypto_box.find('div',class_='sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 cPNAgw').p.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'p'
```

Comment: Some <tr>'s are like this. `<tr class="sc-14kwl6f-0 fletOv"><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td><td><a class="cmc-link" href="/it/currencies/bitcoin-cash/"><span class="circle"></span><span>Bitcoin Cash</span><span class="crypto-symbol">BCH</span></a></td><td><span>$<!-- -->676.51</span></td><td><span></span></td></tr>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `crypto_box.find()` call sometimes fails to find a matching `<div>`, so when you call `.p.text` it gives you the error.

A workaround would be to save the result of the find before trying to access the `.p.text` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/it/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

crypto_body = soup.find('tbody')
crypto_boxs = crypto_body.find_all('tr')

for crypto_box in crypto_boxs:
    div = crypto_box.find('div',class_='sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 cPNAgw')
    
    if div:
        crypto_name = div.p.text
        crypto_price = crypto_box.find('div',class_='price___3rj7O').a.text
        print(f'Crypto Name: {crypto_name}')
        print(f'Crypto Price: {crypto_price}')
```

Giving you:

```
Crypto Name: Bitcoin
Crypto Price: €30,566.99
Crypto Name: Ethereum
Crypto Price: €2,069.74
Crypto Name: Tether
Crypto Price: €0.8177
Crypto Name: Binance Coin
Crypto Price: €264.73
Crypto Name: Cardano
Crypto Price: €1.22
Crypto Name: Dogecoin
Crypto Price: €0.2812
Crypto Name: XRP
Crypto Price: €0.7606
Crypto Name: USD Coin
Crypto Price: €0.8165
Crypto Name: Polkadot
Crypto Price: €16.94
Crypto Name: Internet Computer
Crypto Price: €110.31
```

You could also access the data directly via their JSON api as follows:

```
import requests

url = "https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?id=2781,3526,3537,2821,3527,2782,3528,3531,3530,3533,3532,2832,3529,2783,2814,3549,2784,2786,2787,2820,3534,2815,3535,2788,2789,3536,3538,2790,3539,3540,3541,3542,2792,2793,2818,2796,2794,3544,3543,2795,3545,2797,3546,3551,3547,3550,3548,3552,3556,2800,2816,2799,3555,3558,3554,3557,3559,3561,2811,2802,3560,2819,2801,3562,2804,3563,2822,2803,2805,2791,3564,2817,2806,3566,3565,2808,2812,2798,3567,3573,3553,2807,2785,2809,3569,3568,2810,3570,2824,2813,3571,3572,2823,1,1027,2010,1839,6636,52,1975,2,512,1831,7083,74,9023,9022&convert_id=2781"
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.json()['data']

for symbol in data.values():
    price = symbol['quote']['2781']['price']
    print(f"{symbol['name']} - {price:.4f}")
```

I suggest you `print(data)` to see what data is actually returned.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. Your answer helped me a lot

Comment: Just another quick question. How do you create the web-api link?

Comment: I just watched what the browser requested using the built in dev tools

Comment: Awesome. Thank you